# Activity destroyed after calling another internal Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have an Main activity (I called it Activity A) which creates and attaches a fragment A like so:

```
public onCreate(...){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_space);
FragmentManager fragmentMgr = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentMgr.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction =  fagmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_fragments, FragmentA.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Clicking on a button in Fragment A will cause Fragment A to ask Activity A to start Activity B like so:

```
Intent intentActivityB = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intentActivityB);
```

Then Activity B starts and creates a FragmentB like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_space);
    FragmentManager fragmentMgr = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentMgr.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragments, FragmentB.newInstance(isUpdate, position));
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Problem:

When I pressed the UP button in FragmentB, system displays FragmentA, like I expected. The problem is that FragmentA's state is lost. After putting in some debug statement, I observed that
when I pressed the UP button in FragmentB, ActivityA is created from onCreate() with null Bundle and that means FragmentA is also called on onCreate() with null Bundle. This explains why my state is not restored.

Why is ActivityA destroyed when it starts ActivityB?

How to restore  FragmentA's state?

Is ActivityA and ActivityB using the same Back Stack or each Activity has a different Back Stack?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: to answer some of the questions u've asked. 
1. Activity A is not destroyed, only onStop is called on Activity A after opening Activity B. But, when you go back, it starts from onRestart. On destroy should not have been called on ur Activity A unless you have explicitly killed the activity using finish().
2. To maintain and restore Fragment A's state, check the method retainInstance method on fragment.
3. to maintain and restore the instance on Activity check saveInstanceSstate() & restoreInstanceState() of activity.

Comment: @vi"On destroy should not have been called on ur Activity A unless you have explicitly killed the activity using finish()"

Comment: @vibhor_shri I did not call finish(). However, now I know what destroyed it. In my manifest, the activity A was defaulted to standard mode. This tells Android to create a new Activity A everytime, I clicked on UP button. I learned this behaviour in the Android Developer.com. I changed the mode and now Android restarts the in-memory Activity A. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: great... thanks for sharing with the community... vote up...